# Guaranteed way to associate speech recognition result with an utterance?

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft's C# API for the Cognitive Services (Project Oxford) Bing Speech Recognition service. Specifically, I am using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64 version 0.4.10.2.

I send audio to the [`DataRecognitionClient`](https://staging.www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/Windows/html/ff4169e5-6142-558a-92af-48618f592f39.htm) using the [`SendAudio`](https://staging.www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/Windows/html/de9bea6b-ea8a-84ff-57f5-2e89652498e7.htm) and [`EndAudio`](https://staging.www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/Windows/html/cf887e47-59d0-130c-4b20-30996c4fd306.htm) methods, and wait for the final set of recognition hypotheses via the [`OnResponseReceived`](https://staging.www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/Windows/html/74688a17-01b9-4469-53f3-a8e982545d31.htm) event.  The issue I'm running into is that it's easily possible to have more than one oustanding recognition request, and the  [`SpeechResponseEventArgs`](https://staging.www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/Windows/html/2531addd-d625-26a4-a991-a98aab730b27.htm) object passed to the `OnResponseReceived` handler doesn't contain any information telling me which request it is a response for.

Here's an example that has actually happened to me many times:

1. Person says something, call it utterance A, and I send it via `SendAudio` and then call `EndAudio` when they are done talking.
2. While still waiting to get the `OnResponseReceived` event for utterance A, the person says something else, call it utterance B. Again I send it via `SendAudio` and then call `EndAudio` when they're done talking.  I still haven't gotten an `OnResponseReceived` event.
3. I finally get my first `OnResponseReceived` event.
4. I get a second `OnResponseReceived` event.

How can I correctly associate the responses with the utterances?

Is there an ordering guarantee such that if I send utterance A and then B, I will always get the response for utterance A first?  I haven't seen that guarantee in the documentation.

Comment: Do you mean is there a way to guarantee that the speech-to-text will be exactly correct every time?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, I think OP wants to know how to ensure that the correct response correlates with the correct speech input. The issue is he doesn't know which response is coordinated with which speech with the `onResponseReceived` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the requests are asyc requests there is no guarantee that A will always come after B. The best approach I would recommend is to create a pool of recognitionclients and use one for every recognition and manage the dependency,

Comment: Yeah, I was considering that.  Thanks for the nudge forward.